# Styling Contact Form 7 fields

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, css

We are using wordpress plugin contact form 7 and want to specify the width of the subject field (assume answer would apply to setting width of any field) and relocate the Your Email next to the Your Name field. Result would be Email and Name on one line, Subject full width underneath, Your Message underneath Subject.
Thanks

Comment: Without further information this seem like a pure CSS question, which would be off topic per the [faq]

Comment: Contact form 7 lets you put whatever HTML you need to into forms, look at it's admin screen.  Also: show us what you've tried. Right now this sounds like an off topic CSS question, as @s_ha_dum said.

Comment: I am quite familiar with CSS, but couldn't locate it in the Appearance/Editor page. Nor could I find an .php files, so had no idea where to start. I see the admin screen which contains the shortcode, but I've never tried to modify shortcode, so didn't know where to find it. Any suggestions would help me get off the dime. Sorry if I'm in the wrong place. I thought I saw other contact form 7 questions here.

Comment: Give your CSS suggestion, I used Firefox's Tools/Web Developer/Inspect feature (so handy!) to at least change the width to match the comment block. I contribute it here for others to use:

Comment: /* Widen input field on form */
input[type="text"], textarea {
  width:80%

Answer (score 1):

I din't try it, but have a try yourself:

Contact Form 7 uses something like this:

```
<p>Your Name (required)<br />
    [text* your-name] </p>
```

Instead of using paragraph tag (`<p>`) use span (`<span>`), and some inline CSS, like:

```
<span style="width: 48%; float: left; position: relative;">Your Name (required)<br />
    [text* your-name] </span>

<span style="width: 48%; float: left; position: relative;">Your Email (required)<br />
    [email* your-email] </span>
```

`width: 48%` will let you do some `margin` things. Then use a `<div>` to clear the `float` from all sides:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Then the other codes:

```
<p>Subject<br />
    [text your-subject] </p>

<p>Your Message<br />
    [textarea your-message] </p>

<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

So the whole bunch of codes will be:

```
<span style="width: 48%; float: left; position: relative;">Your Name (required)<br />
    [text* your-name] </span>

<span style="width: 48%; float: left; position: relative;">Your Email (required)<br />
    [email* your-email] </span>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<p>Subject<br />
    [text your-subject] </p>

<p>Your Message<br />
    [textarea your-message] </p>

<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

DON'T FORGET TO CHANGE THE SPECIFIC SLUGS LIKE `your-email`, `your-subject` SPECIFIC TO YOUR CONTACT FORM IDs.
Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Much more simple than the previous answer:

add classes to your input fields in the form builder - `[text* your-name class:your-name]`

Then style it in your CSS file.

Example:

`#wpcf7-f613-p57-o1 form .your-name {width:48%;}` - Where `#wpcf7-f613-p57-o1` is the id of the form you're working with.